Could not resolve com.github.webassembly:binaryen when attempting to build Kotlin Multiplatform sample project
I'm attempting to build a Kotlin Mutiplatform sample project downloaded from the Kotlin Multiplatform Wizard (https://kmp.jetbrains.com/).  I'm doing this on a corporate network where all network traffic has to go thru a proxy server. However, the build fails with the following error.  It appears that gradle is not honoring our proxy settings.  Anyone know how to resolve this?
Note that I am able to download this file in the browser and via curl, so our proxy configuration is correct and is also working for normal gradle dependencies required by this project.  The only problems we are seeing are for internal dependencies like the one listed below.

What went wrong:

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':kotlinBinaryenSetup'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.


Could not resolve com.github.webassembly:binaryen:118.

 Required by:

     project :

  > Could not resolve com.github.webassembly:binaryen:118.

     > Could not get resource 'https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/releases/download/version_118/binaryen-version_118-x86_64-macos.tar.gz'.

        > Could not HEAD 'https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/releases/download/version_118/binaryen-version_118-x86_64-macos.tar.gz'.

           > Got SSL handshake exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration

              > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target


"...is also working for normal gradle dependencies required by this project. The only problems we are seeing are for internal dependencies like the one listed below" -- how are you defining "internal dependencies"? IOW, what is the difference between dependencies that work and dependencies that do not?

explicit dependencies declared in the dependencies section of the build.gradle are being downloaded correctly.  The ones we are having trouble with are the ones that the gradle tasks are trying to load directly.  These appear to ignore both our repository and proxy settings. Note that if I comment out the JS target, I see the same failures for other 'internal' dependencies required by the IOS target.

It sounds like what you are referring to as 'internal' dependencies are what Gradle would refer to as 'transitive' dependencies. That said, I have no good explanation for the symptoms that you are seeing.

Perhaps, though I would expect a transitive dependency to use the same repositories & proxy settings that the explicit dependencies are using.  I feel like this is just a direct download that the task is attempting?  For instance, here is the another variation of this issue that I'm seeing if I comment out the JS target:

Task :composeApp:compileIosMainKotlinMetadata

Downloading native dependencies (LLVM, sysroot etc). This is a one-time action performed only on the first run of the compiler.
Cannot download a dependency: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed
